# How can I access the shardArgs from the ShardClientUtil, using the sharding manager?

Tags: node.js, sharding, discord.js

I'm setting up a Bot using Discord.JS and want to pass the [`shardArgs`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ShardingManager?scrollTo=shardArgs) option from the `ShardingManager` to the `ShardClient`. How do I access the option (`shardArgs`) from the `ShardClientUtil`?

```
// ShardManager.js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const Manager = new Discord.ShardingManager('./Main.js', {
     shardArgs: ["shard args to be passed through"]
});

Manager.spawn(1);
```

I've tried using [`.fetchClientValues()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ShardClientUtil?scrollTo=fetchClientValues):

```
// Main.js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.shard.fetchClientValues('manager.shardArgs') 
   .then(results => {
    console.log(results);
   })
   .catch(console.error);

client.login("token");
```

I've tried many different things, I even checked the object in a debugger, but I was unable to find `shardArgs` so I'm not sure where I'm supposed to access it from.

I expect `shardArgs` to be `"shard args to be passed through"`, while at the moment I'm getting `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `shardArgs` are actually passed around a bit:

- First to [`Shard`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.4.2/class/Shard)'s constructor
- Then to [`Shard#spawn`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.4.2/class/Shard?scrollTo=spawn)
- Finally to [`child_process.fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) (which will start the shard's process)

---

You can access your array in your shards via [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv). (No need for IPC)

Mind that the first entry is the exeuctable (node) and the second is the file being executed (Main.js), the third and up entries are your array's.

As an example logging `process.argv` in your `Main.js` file might log:
`['usr/bin/node', '/home/bot/Main.js', 'shard args to be passed through']`